# Do you have a working definition of remainder function for polynomials in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I have this function below, but can't seem to use it to manually evaluate poly-division remainders:

```
(define (poly-scale poly n) (map (lambda (x) (* x n)) poly))

(define (poly-remainder poly1 poly2)
  (let
      ((scale (/ (leading-coef poly1) (leading-coef poly2))))
    (if (< (degree poly1) (degree poly2)) poly1
    (poly-remainder (rest-of-poly (p+ (poly-scale poly2 (* scale -1)) poly1)) 
           poly2))))
```

Unfortunately, there are a ton of helping functions here. Program [5.14 on p. 23(pdf)](http://www.little-lisper.org/website/files/locally-defined-procedures.pdf) contains most of them. Definition of p^+ is [Program 5.9 on p.18(pdf)](http://www.little-lisper.org/website/files/locally-defined-procedures.pdf).

Two more helping functions:

```
(define list-of-zeros
   (lambda(n)
     (cond
      ((zero? n) '())
      (else (cons 0 (list-of-zeros (sub1 n)))))))

(define sub1
   (lambda(n)
     (- n 1)))
```

Here's my attempt to manually evaluate the the remainder of (x^2 - 2) / (x + 1):

```
(poly-remainder '(1 0 -2) '(1 1))
 (poly-remainder (rest-of-poly (p+ (poly-scale poly2 (* scale -1)) poly1)) poly2))
 (poly-remainder (rest-of-poly (p+ (poly-scale poly2 -1) poly1)) poly2))
 (poly-remainder (rest-of-poly (p+ (-1 -1) poly1)) poly2))
 (poly-remainder (rest-of-poly (1 -1 -3)) poly2))
 (poly-remainder (-1 -3) poly2))
 (poly-remainder (rest-of-poly (p+ (poly-scale poly2 (* scale -1)) poly1)) poly2))        
 (poly-remainder (rest-of-poly (p+ (1 1) poly1)) poly2))
 (poly-remainder (rest-of-poly (0 -2)) poly2))
 (poly-remainder (-2) poly2))
 (-2)
```

But the remainder is supposed to be (-1).

Please, show me my mistake. If the poly- remainder is incorrectly defined, can you please fix it or maybe you know a nice alternative?

Answer (score 0):

In `poly-remainder` the purpose of

```
(p+ (poly-scale poly2 (* scale -1)) poly1)
```

is to cancel out the leading term of poly1.

But ... what happens when the degrees of poly2 is smaller than the degree of poly1?

You need to multiply poly2 with `x^(m-n)` where m and n are there degrees of poly1 and poly2 respectively. I believe you can do so by appending `m-n` zeros to poly2.